# error using http.post in angular2

Tags: angular, angular-services

I am getting 400 (Bad Request) error.
The method `search($event,'btn')` is called on the click of button in `abc.component.html`,which later calls some method in service to fetch data.

Here, `getFilteredData()` method is providing data while `searchData()` method is not providing data but providing 400 error.[Here is the image showing error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lO9bn.png)

**abc.component.html**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="searchData" class="form-control"  type="text" placeholder="Search Keywords : 'Lenovo', 'May', 'New York'" style="height: 30px;" />
<input  type="checkbox" id="chckbox" [(ngModel)]="checked" class="form-control"  style="width: 34px;height: 32px;margin:0px;" #chkbox checked>

<button (click)="search($event,'btn')" class="btn btn-success" style="height:30px;padding: 0px 30px">Search </button>
```

**json-data.service.ts**

```
searchData(searchText:JsonData): Observable<JsonData[]> {
            console.log('Retriving Data from Solr Server.......');
            let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
            let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
            let url = "http://192.10/PIdString";
            return this.http.post(url,searchText,options).map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
          }

getFilteredData(searchText:JsonData): Observable<JsonData[]> {
                console.log('Retriving Data from Solr Server.......' + JSON.stringify(searchText));
                let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
                let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
                let url = "http://1921.le"; //Local Server
                return this.http.post(url, searchText,options).map((res: Response) => res.json()).catch(this.handleError);
              }
```

**abc.component.ts**

```
checked:boolean = true;
          constructor(public jsonDataService: JsonDataService, public injector: Injector) { }

      search(event, from) {
            if(this.checked){
              alert("checked");
            }
            else{
              alert("unchecked");
            }
            if (this.searchData === "" || this.searchData === null) {
           alert("Enter any keyword to search !");
            }else if(this.checked === true && this.searchData === "" || this.searchData === null ){
              alert("Enter any keyword to search !");
            }else if(this.checked !== true && this.searchData === "" || this.searchData === null){
        alert("Enter any keyword to search !");
            }else if(this.checked === true && (this.searchData !== "" || this.searchData !== null)){
        console.log("checked");
        console.log("Searching.......");
           this.jsonDataService.getFilteredData(this.searchData).subscribe(
                  success => this.buildDataUI1(success),
                  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);  
            }
            else if(this.checked === false && (this.searchData !== "" || this.searchData !== null)){
              console.log("unchecked");
              console.log("Searching.......");
                 this.jsonDataService.searchData(this.searchData).subscribe(
                    success => this.buildDataUI1(success),
                    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);      
            } 
        }
```

Comment: An error 400 means you don't send a payload that the back-end epxects. What does your back-end expects, and what do you send exactly ? You can see it in The Chome console under the network tab

Comment: Actually, i am new to angular2. Here one method is getting data and other is giving error as you can see both methods are same except url request.

Comment: They are the same but they don't call the same endpoint. As I just said above, the endpoint returns an error 400, meaning you don't send the correct data. So please, post both what the front-end sends, and what the back-end accepts.

Comment: can you please share your API side code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see what your `JSONData` is like so I'm only guessing.

- Your model `searchData` seems to be a string based on your `<input>` placeholder.
- Your component passes `searchData` as it is to your service functions.
- Your service functions passes `searchData` as it is directly as your `POST` payload.

Your endpoint is probably expecting a JSON string, not a plain string.